# Can't connect to MariaDB via MATLAB - Invalid MEX File

Tags: mysql, matlab, dll

I am trying to connect to MariaDB using mYm (Mysql wrapper for MATLAB) on MATLAB.
Every time I use mYm to access DB I get an error

`Invalid MEX-file 'path\to\DB\MySQL\mYm1.36 64-bit\mym.mexw64': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.`

So far what I've understood is that DLL in question i.e. `libmysql.dll` is not registered.I tried do do that using `regsvr32 "path\to\DB\MySQL\mYm1.36 64-bit\libmysql.dll"`. But that results in following error:

```
The module path\to\DB\MySQL\mYm1.36 64-bit\libmysql.dll failed to load. 
Make sure the binary is stored at specified path or debug it to check for problems with binary or dependent .DLL files.
The specified module could not be found.
```

I require a solution to fix this error.
I might be wrong in assuming the dll is not registered.

Comment: You need more information here to pin-point the problem. Use the [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com) tool to see what libraries are used by the MEX-file, and if they can be found. Who build the MEX-file? Is it compatible with your versions of MATLAB and Windows? Do you have the required Visual Studio runtime installed?

Comment: @CrisLuengo the problem solved on it's own. I don't know how? I didn't restarted my PC or made any changes. I am trying to figure out what caused this.